# flutter firebase get array from Firestore and assign it to a list

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection in Firestore. It has a field array i am trying to get the array from Firestore and assign it to a list in flutter.
My collection is as below

[image]

My code for getting data from Firestore

```
List<Offset> pointlist = <Offset>[];

 getdata() async{
  await Firestore.instance.collection("points").document('biZV7cepFJA8T6FTcF08').get().then((value){
setState(() {

List<Offset> pointlist = List.from(value.data['point']);

});
   });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getdata();
  }
```

i get this error type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Offset'

Comment: It seems that `value.data['point']` can't be converted to a `List<Offset>`... can you show what is `value.data['point']`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing which you are doing wrong is this:

```
// You have initialised your List as a Offset Object Type
List<Offset> pointList;
```

> Secondly, the data you are assigning is a `String`, if you closely take a look at that firebase.

```
"Offset(x,y)"
```

> Finally, trying to assign the `String` value to a `List` of type `Offset class/object`

> If you want to make the thing works, then either make the `List` of type `String` and then add it to the `List`

```
List<String> pointlist = List.from(value.data['point']);
```

> Or first Add the data to the Offset Object like this, and then pass it to the List

```
List<Offset> pointList = <Offset>[];

getdata() async{
  await Firestore.instance.collection("points").document('biZV7cepFJA8T6FTcF08').get().then((value){
setState(() {
      // first add the data to the Offset object
      List.from(value.data['point']).forEach((element){
          Offset data = new Offset(element);

          //then add the data to the List<Offset>, now we have a type Offset
          pointList.add(data);
      });

      });
   });
  }
```

**SUMMARY**

Always look for the data type you are giving to the `List`, if you are trying to add the data which is not a type `T` of `List<T>`, you will always get this error of type mismatch. Hope this will give you some clarity and some basic idea about programming. Keep learning :)

Comment: Happy to help @RavitejaReddy :)

Comment: There is a small problem .Offset needs two data dx,dy .List.from(value.data['point']).forEach((element){
          Offset data = new Offset(element); But here as we are giving only one argument it is giving an error saying 2 positional arguments expected

Comment: Yeah @RavitejaReddy I just gave you an explanation about why you were facing the problem. I did not have the full access to the code. Now we can go ahead and tackle the situation. The problem is, element get's this data only, **"Offset(dx, dy)"** from your firebase. If you want to pass those data, then, **is it possible to only store dx, and dy like this `[dx, dy]` in your Firebase, or Offset(dx, dy) is mandatory**?

Comment: Hey alok got it .i saved both dx and dy in two arrays and called them back as an offset and it worked.Thank you

Comment: Great @RavitejaReddy, happy to help you or give you some guidance for it. All the very best :)

Answer (score 1):

you have to declare list and all list item will be store in declared list so you can access it.

```
 List<dynamic> alldata =[];

    Future<QuerySnapshot?> getData() async {
        dataofItem = FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('$data')
            .get()
            .then((QuerySnapshot? querySnapshot) {
          querySnapshot!.docs.forEach((doc) {
            allData = doc["item_text_"];
            print("allData = $allData");
            //  print("getData = ${doc["item_text_"]}");
          });
        });
        return dataofItem;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume the structure to be.

```
...
arrayOfString
 |_element1
 |_element2
 |_element3
...
```

---

Use the following code to get the array elements of `arrayOfString` parameter

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('users')
              .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
              .snapshots(),
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return const Text('Something went wrong');
            }
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const Text("Loading");
            }
            Map<String, dynamic> data =
                snapshot.data!.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
            return ListView(
                children: data['arrayOfString'].map<Widget>((e) {  arrayOfString has array of Strings
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(e.toString()), //  printing every string
              );
            }).toList());
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```