# How can I fetch the array from my firebase to flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I have a simple app where I want to fetch all of my data and show it but I can only fetch the simple strings (name,id and size) but whenever i try to fetch the Array it errors :(
Can someone give a simple and quick example how to fetch the array of strings into my flutter app?

[image: pic]

```
class _PokedexHomeState extends State<PokedexHome> {
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      appBar: AppBar(
          leading: const Icon(MdiIcons.pokeball),
          centerTitle: true,
          title: const Center(child: Text('Pokédex')),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: readPokemon(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Text('Couldn\u0027t find any Pokémon :( ');
          } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final users = snapshot.data!;
            return GridView.count(
              //amount of cards next to eachother
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              childAspectRatio: (1 / .5),
              children: users.map((e) => buildPokemon(e, context)).toList(),
            );
          } else {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Pokemon {
  String id;
  final String name;
  final String size;
  final List<dynamic> elements;

  Pokemon(
      {this.id = '',
      required this.name,
      required this.size,
      required this.elements});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
      {'id': id, 'name': name, 'size': size, 'elements': elements};

  static Pokemon fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Pokemon(
      id: json['id'],
      name: json['name'],
      size: json['size'],
      elements: json['elements'] as List<dynamic>);
}
```

Comment: This post from the stackoverflow might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63091889/flutter-firebase-get-array-from-firestore-and-assign-it-to-a-list

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
json['elements'] as List<dynamic>
```

to

```
List.from(json['elements'])
```